# How to do this?: DataTable.Select("[Enabled].ToUpper ='TRUE'")

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there a way to include an embedded .NET function in a DataTable Filter? I assume not. Please see my embedded comments in the code pertaining to the ToUpper function that I want to include.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Linq

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())

        Dim MyTable As DataTable = New DataTable()

        MyTable.Columns.Add("Key", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        MyTable.Columns.Add("Enabled", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))

        Dim Row1 As DataRow
        Row1 = MyTable.NewRow()
        Row1.Item("Key") = 1
        Row1.Item("Enabled") = "true"
        MyTable.Rows.Add(Row1)

        Dim Row2 As DataRow
        Row2 = MyTable.NewRow()
        Row2.Item("Key") = 2
        Row2.Item("Enabled") = "True"
        MyTable.Rows.Add(Row2)

        Dim Row3 As DataRow
        Row3 = MyTable.NewRow()
        Row3.Item("Key") = 3
        Row3.Item("Enabled") = "False"
        MyTable.Rows.Add(Row3)

        'I wish this would work but I assume that the DataTable object's Filter method doesn't support embedded .NEt Functions?
        Dim MyFilteredTable As DataTable = Test(MyTable, "[Enabled].ToUpper ='TRUE'")

        'So I am forced to check for reasonably likely literal combinations
        MyFilteredTable = Test(MyTable, "[Enabled] ='True' OR [Enabled] ='TRUE'  OR [Enabled] ='true'")

    End Sub

    Private Function Test(Collection_In As DataTable, Select_Condition As String)

        Dim Collection_Out As DataTable

        Dim NewRow As DataRow

        Collection_Out = Collection_In.Clone

        For Each parentRow As DataRow In Collection_In.Select(Select_Condition)

            NewRow = Collection_Out.NewRow

            For Each c As DataColumn In NewRow.Table.Columns
                NewRow(c.ColumnName) = parentRow(c.ColumnName)
            Next
            Collection_Out.Rows.Add(NewRow)
        Next

        NewRow = Nothing
        Collection_In = Nothing

        Return Collection_Out

    End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple solution to your problem.
Instead of the = operator use the LIKE operator

```
Dim MyFilteredTable As DataTable = Test(MyTable, "[Enabled] LIKE 'TRUE'")
```

also, all the code in test method, could be reduced to

```
Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(Collection_In, Select_Condition, "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
Return dv.ToTable()
```

Comment: Thanks. I would've expected that LIKE was to be used with WILDCARD searche, not case sensitivity. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is wrong in implying that the DataColumn Expression `Like` comparison operator imparts some special case-insensitive feature.

From: [DataColumn.Expression Property - String Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2#string-operators)

> To concatenate a string, use the + character. The value of the
>   CaseSensitive property of the DataSet class determines whether string
>   comparisons are case-sensitive. However, you can override that value
>   with the CaseSensitive property of the DataTable class.

The reason the `Like` operator works for the OP sample code is that default value for the `DataTable.CaseSensitive` property is `False` (the default value).  The following statement will yield a DataTable with two rows with the `[Enabled]` field set to some case-insensitive equivalent of "tRuE" as long as the table is configured to do case-insensitive comparisons.

```
Dim MyFilteredTable As DataTable = (New DataView(MyTable, "[Enabled] ='tRuE'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)).ToTable()
```

From: [DataTable.CaseSensitive Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.casesensitive?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> true if the comparison is case-sensitive; otherwise false. The default
>   is set to the parent DataSet object's CaseSensitive property, or **false
>   if the DataTable was created independently** of a DataSet.

Also pay attention to: [Parsing Literal Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2#parsing-literal-expressions)

> All literal expressions must be expressed in the invariant culture
>   locale. When DataSet parses and converts literal expressions, it
>   always uses the invariant culture, not the current culture.

Comment: I like your analysis of the situation but saying that my answer is wrong when it gives the result expected seems a bit too harsh to me. However I believe that you have given an excellent answer.

Comment: @steve, re-read the 1st sentence.  I said the implication of `Like` operator being case-insensitive is wrong and I stand by that.  Remember its the answer not you.